# Offspring with different gender

Tags: netlogo

I hope I submit it this time in easy and simple way, I used this code to create turtles  in each patch, then I assinged them as parents ( male is blue and female is pink)

```
turtles-own [ gender] 
to setup 
ask patches [ 
 sprout  1 
 [set size 0.2 
set color pink 
set gender "female" 

  ]] 
ask patches [ 
 sprout  1 
 [set size 0.2 
set color blue 
set gender "male" 



    ]] 

 reset-ticks 

end
```

I want to have offspring from only one female each tick in each group with different gender (males and females ) . I tried to use hatch from one of the females but all the offspring were females and when I use create it said error as it is observer only. {{ the idea is to make groups as families and each family has their father, mather and different gender offspring }} 
Please can someone help me to modify this code . 
and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "group". Do all the turtles together on a patch constitute a group, or what? (I'll assume that's what you mean.)

The following code finds all the patches where there is at least one male and one female present, then on each such patch, has one female hatch an offspring turtle of random gender.

```
to-report parents-here?  ;; patch procedure
  report any? turtles-here with [gender = "male"]
         and
         any? turtles-here with [gender = "female"]
end

to go
  ask patches with [parents-here?] [
    ask one-of turtles-here with [gender = "female"] [
      hatch 1 [
        set gender one-of ["male" "female"]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you million of times , ur code helped me alot .

Comment: If you dont mind , I want to ask you , If I want to say ask one or 2 females to hatch. your code solve my problem but when I tried to add n-of 2 , there was error said no this patch has only two, what I want is to ask if one present can hatch and if 2 also can hatch

Comment: Please open a new question and say exactly what result you were trying to achieve, exactly what code you tried, and exactly what error message you got.